# Can I have two sessions of tmux in separate panels?

Tags: tmux

Like in the title, I'm trying to get three sessions of `tmux` in separate panes, each for every game server I have[image: example in paint]

Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can... just run `tmux` after `TMUX=` so you can have a nested session:

```
TMUX= tmux
```

[image]

Comment: Ok... that was easier then i expected, problem was i tried to attach another session on other pane without TMUX=
I hope rest of total linux newbies will take a lesson from mine mistakes. :D